# What are the benefits of this type of JFET biasing

Tags: amplifier, jfet, small-signal

The next schemtaic I was found as an input stage of ultra-linear phono amplifier.

[image]

1. What are the benefits of that type of biasing? I don't see that 12V zener has 12V voltage drop on it (only 4.2V) and in this situation how I can predict the Q-point of JFET?
2. What JFET's may be used with such schematic? I take JFET 2n4391 and the voltage gain of the stage drops dramatically.

Comment: You are quite right, Q point is practically unpredictable. it's not an ultra linear phono preamplifier, it's an ultra-bad phono pre :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of the circuit is that the Vds of the JFET is kept constant at about 12 V (more accurately: 12 V - Vbe_q2 = 11.3 V). Keeping the Vds constant eliminates any influence Vds has on the voltage-to-current transfer (Id / Vgs) of the JFET.

If you do not have 12 V at the cathode of the zener D1 then the circuit is not biased correctly. Then most of the current flowing through R2 goes into the base of Q2 and then to Q1.

Solution: lower the value of R2. D1 is a 1 W zener diode so it can handle 1 W /12 V = 83 mA. Let's say we use 20 mA through R2: 20 V - 12 V = 8 V, 8 V / 20 mA = 400 ohms. Hmm, that's a lot less than the 4.7 kohm you have.

What JFETs you can use depends on the JFET's properties. Look in the datasheet what the Id will be when Vgs = 0 as that is how the JFET is biased here.

I expect that you will also have to lower the value of R1 if you use a JFET with a Vgs=0 current of more than 8V / 2.4 kohm = 3 mA. Lowering R1 will also reduce the voltage gain though.

As an input for a low distortion phono amplifier, I have my doubts about this circuit. To really have low distortion you cannot beat feedback. A good solution could be a JFET based differential pair to provide a limited amount of gain. Then an opamp or opamp like circuit and overall feedback. That will hands down beat this circuit distortion wise.

Comment: 2SK170 datasheet tells that Id will be near 9ma when Vgs = 0V but how it can work when Id has only 3ma current? And why 2SK170 datasheet tells that minimal Idss near 2.6ma but I'm working now on more that 3ma to 10ma?

Comment: *but how it can work when Id has only 3ma current?* Like I wrote: it will not. You will have to lower the value of R1 such that 3.3 mA can flow while taking care that Q1 still has enough Vce. The datasheet states that Idss is between 2.6 mA and 20 mA so 3.3 mA is still in that range. Idss just **varies a lot** and **the manufacturer has little control over it**. That's one of the reasons JFETs are not used like this (relying on Idss), Idss just varies too much. When used in a differential pair, the Id is set in a different way (using a current source for example), that gives more control.

Comment: Can you show sample two-stage JFET amplifier schematic with JFET differential input stage and one voltage amplifier stage on JFET with current source for stable bias and feedback loop?

Comment: Here's one: https://www.data-odyssey.nl/Super_TIS.html  figure 16. How did I find that? I Google for "JFET input amplifier" then click the "images" tab and look for the right schematic.

Comment: If the Drain-Source voltage is fixed then the DC part of that doesn't vary but what about AC - is it correct that it's vary and adds to fixed DC part according to superposition principle?

Comment: AC is just small variations on the DC. In this testbench the idea is to keep Vds constant for DC but also for AC. The AC variation is in the **current** which goes through Q2 and will give an AC voltage across R1.

Comment: If I take opposite case - I don't use Vds stabilization and use current source instead of Q2 then I'll stabilize the drain current DC and AC but variations will be in drain-source voltage instead of previous situation, so?

Comment: *and use current source instead of Q2* It makes no sense to do that as the Q1 also behaves as a current source. You should not connect two current sources in series. Also the signal is a current and you would be overruling it with your current source. To force a constant Ids you would need a different setup.

Comment: During simulation I can't understand why if I set R2 = 400 oHm and achieve 12V on D1 the schematic doesn't work properly with R1 = 2.4 kOhm? I_R1 = 3.6 ma in simulator but it only current through R1, the Q1 Drain current is always near 10.6 ma for wide range of R1 because Drain current is equal to summ of I_R1 and I_R2/(Beta_Q2 + 1). But the output on oscilloscope shows good amlification only for R1 much smaller that on schematic. Why there is no amplification for R1 as on schematic if the drain current always same?

Comment: When R1 = 2.4 k and Id_Q1 = 10.6 mA then Q2 is in **saturation mode**, Q2 then delivers most of the current through the base instead of from the collector. You must lower the value of R1 so that Q2 operates in **active mode** only then will you see proper current amplification Ic/Ib.

Comment: i. e. if I take 12 V on D1 then I'll get 7.3 V on (V_R1 + Vce_Q2). To find R1 I take 10 ma on R1, but what voltage on R1 I must take? I need to drop some voltage on CE of Q2 to move it in "active mode". What voltage I need - half of 7.3V or something else?

Comment: *I need to drop some voltage on CE of Q2 to move it in "active mode"* **No, you don't** In active mode Vce needs to be **large** so the voltage across R1 needs to be **small**. If you make R1 0 ohms (a short) then Q2 is **guaranteed** to be in active mode. I would choose R1 to drop 1 Volt at 10 mA so that's 100 ohms. R1 is only there to monitor the current on the scope. For the operation of the circuit R1 isn't even needed.

Comment: Is it correct that Q2 acts like a common-collector amplifier with a load in emitter equal to Q1? And is it correct that Q2 only behaves like a current source but not the current source in reality because Ve_Q1 is fixed but Id_Q1 varies with AC signal?

Comment: *Q2 is a common collector*: correct. Q2 does **not** behave like a current source, on the emitter Q2 actually behaves as a voltage source (zener voltage - Vbe), then the **current** needed to sustain that voltage flows into the collector (minus the base current) and that current is what we're interested in as it is the drain current of Q1. And indeed that Id of Q1 varies with the AC signal. Q2 is a **cascode**, I suggest reading up on cascodes.